# Yarn - why doesn't task go out of heap space but container gets killed?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

If a YARN container grows beyond its heap size setting, the map or reduce task will fail, with an error similar to the one below:

```
2015-02-06 11:58:15,461 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Container [pid=10305,containerID=container_1423215865404_0002_01_000007] is running beyond physical memory limits. 
Current usage: 42.1 GB of 42 GB physical memory used; 42.9 GB of 168 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_1423215865404_0002_01_000007 :
        |- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE
        |- 10310 10305 10305 10305 (java) 1265097 48324 46100516864 11028122 /usr/java/default/bin/java -server -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill %p -Xms40960m -Xmx40960m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Dspark.sql.shuffle.partitions=20 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/data/yarn/datanode/nm-local-dir/usercache/admin/appcache/application_1423215865404_0002/container_1423215865404_0002_01_000007/tmp org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend akka.tcp://sparkDriver@marx-61:56138/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler 6 marx-62 5
        |- 10305 28687 10305 10305 (bash) 0 0 9428992 318 /bin/bash -c /usr/java/default/bin/java -server -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill %p' -Xms40960m -Xmx40960m  -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Dspark.sql.shuffle.partitions=20 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/data/yarn/datanode/nm-local-dir/usercache/admin/appcache/application_1423215865404_0002/container_1423215865404_0002_01_000007/tmp org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend akka.tcp://sparkDriver@marx-61:56138/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler 6 marx-62 5 1> /opt/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1423215865404_0002/container_1423215865404_0002_01_000007/stdout 2> /opt/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1423215865404_0002/container_1423215865404_0002_01_000007/stderr
```

It is interesting to note that all stages complete, just when save as sequence file is called, it fails. The executor is not using up the heap space, wonder what else is eating it up?

Comment: which container is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark executor gets killed all the time and Spark keeps retrying the failed stage. For Spark on YARN, nodemanager would kill Spark executor if it used more memory than the configured size of "spark.executor.memory" + "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead".  Increase "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead" to make sure it covers the executor off-heap memory usage.

Some issues:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2398
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2468

Comment: This is a good analysis. However if you see OP's container is running out of physical memory NOT virtual memory. so if he just disable 'yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled' in yarn-site.xml then nodemanager should keep the container untill 168GB of virtual memory is hit. I was having same issue and I tried that but it didn't work. spark jobs don't honor virtual memory limit.

Comment: what exactly is 'memoryOverhead' ? I see in doc "The amount of off heap memory (in megabytes) to be allocated per executor. This is memory that accounts for things like VM overheads, interned strings, other native overheads, etc. This tends to grow with the executor size (typically 6-10%)" But why strings and VM overheads will be more then 10% in some cases like mine as mine still fails with 10% of executor memory.

Answer (score 2):

You are actually running the container out of physical memory in this case:

Current usage: 42.1 GB of 42 GB physical memory used

The virtual memory isn't the bounding factor.  You'll have to increase the heap size of the container or increase spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead to give some more space to the YARN container without increasing the executor heap size necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

I faced exact same problem as OP, all stages succeeded and only at the time of saving and writing the results, the container would be killed.

If java heap memory is exceeded, you see **OutOfMemory** exceptions but a container being killed is related to everything except java heap memory, which can be either related to memoryOverhead or application master memory.

In my case increasing `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` or `spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead` didn't help because probably it was my application master (AM) getting out of memory. In `yarn-client` mode, the configuration to increase AM memory is `spark.yarn.am.memory`. For `yarn-cluster` mode, it is the driver memory. This is how it worked for me.

Here's a reference to the error I got:

```
Application application_1471843888557_0604 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1471843888557_0604_000002 exited with exitCode: -104
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://master01.prod2.everstring.com:8088/cluster/app/application_1471843888557_0604Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Container [pid=89920,containerID=container_e59_1471843888557_0604_02_000001] is running beyond physical memory limits. 
Current usage: 14.0 GB of 14 GB physical memory used; 16.0 GB of 29.4 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
```